# python find all occurrences of key in JSON and modify value

Tags: python, json, find, compare, key

I have the following problem. Using Python 2.7, I have a JSON and I have to find all occurrences of key "workers".

the value is always a list of integers

```
   workers : [22,14,523,...]
```

and I have to compare them with some other list of integers.

```
 ID = [14,22,26,32,...]
```

in case in workers list one number is missing from ID list  that number in workers has to be removed.

I hope I have made this clear enough.

The problem is this is a nested JSON with different levels.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see an example below. I hope you meant a similar solution.

```
test_ids_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
test_ids_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8]

json_var = [
    {
        "human": {"man":
                      {"workers": [1, 2, 3],
                       "blabla": "abcd"},
                  "woman":
                      {"workers": [4, 5, 6],
                       "blabla": "dcab"}}
    }
]

for worker in json_var[0]["human"]:
    for ids in json_var[0]["human"][worker]["workers"]:
        if ids not in test_ids_1:
            print("%s is missing from test_ids_1 list" % ids)
        if ids not in test_ids_2:
            print("%s is missing from test_ids_2 list" % ids)
```

Output:

```
python test.py 
6 is missing from test_ids_2 list
```

Note: Of course, if you read the Json file and serialize it then you can iterate on it and check the elements. You can see details on this link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html